# Android wallpaper pack

Tags: android

I apologise if this is the wrong place to ask this question, I did my best to make sure it has not been asked before and thorougly searched the web for any similar answer.

So here goes: I am having a very hard time finding any sort of reference, or better yet a tutorial on how to create a wallpaper pack for android.

To elaborate, I do not mean a live wallpaper of any kind. Just a pack of selected wallpapers packaged into an applications for distribution through the market. Ideally wih its own selection interface.

There are precedents on the market but for the life of me I cannot find any information.

Any ideas, opinions or suggestions? Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the GitHub repository for the wallpaper pack that CyanogenMod has. It should be pretty simple to base yours off of this.

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_CMWallpapers